# Find the difference between cells in the same column that match certain criteria

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below:

```
name<-c("ab","ab","ab","ac","ac","ac","d","d","d")
value<-c(9,9,6,10,10,4,8,9,8)
week<-c(31,31,32,31,31,35,32,33,35)
c<-data.frame(name,value,week)
```

I would like to create  a new column with the difference between the week value for every `name`, if a previous `week` exists. If not 0 will be displayed. For the dataframe below the answer would be like:

```
       name value week df
    1   ab     9   31  0
    2   ab     9   31  0
    3   ab     6   32 -3
    4   ac    10   31  0
    5   ac    10   31  0
    6   ac     4   35  0
    7    d     8   32  0
    8    d     9   33  1
    9    d     8   35  0
```

Comment: WRT naming:  `c` is a poor name choice for a dataframe since `c` is a very common R function.  I would also advocate against `df` as a variable name since its commonly used as a shorthand to mean "dataframe".  My recommendation would be to name your dataframe `df` and your new column `diff`, but to each their own.

Comment: @DanY - agreed about `c`, but `diff` is a common function too!

Comment: I can't argue with that :)  I guess I was just trying to pick something more descriptive for the colname; clearly my success was marginal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy enough to do with **dplyr**, and a bit of math to ensure that the difference is only shown if the previous week was exactly 1 less than the current row's week:

```
library(dplyr)

c <- c %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(df = c(0, diff(value)) * as.numeric(c(0, diff(week)) == 1))

  name  value  week    df
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 ab        9    31     0
2 ab        9    31     0
3 ab        6    32    -3
4 ac       10    31     0
5 ac       10    31     0
6 ac        4    35     0
7 d         8    32     0
8 d         9    33     1
9 d         8    35     0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that was it.

Answer (score 2):

Naming your data.frame `df` and your new column `diff`, here's one way to do it with data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[ , diff := ifelse(week-shift(week)==1, value-shift(value), 0), by=name]
df[is.na(diff), diff := 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` using a join to a temporary set moving the week forward one step:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- as.data.table(c)


dat[
  unique(dat[,c(.SD,.(week1=week+1))]),
  on=c("name","week"="week1"),
  dfr := value-i.value
]

dat
#   name value week dfr
#1:   ab     9   31  NA
#2:   ab     9   31  NA
#3:   ab     6   32  -3
#4:   ac    10   31  NA
#5:   ac    10   31  NA
#6:   ac     4   35  NA
#7:    d     8   32  NA
#8:    d     9   33   1
#9:    d     8   35  NA
```